# Azure Logic App : Truncate table before insert records

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

I have a basic logic app with sql Inserting records and it works fine. but here I need to truncate table before insert records.

Is this possible with Azure logic apps? if so how can i achieve this?

**Note:** I am accessing DB using on-premises data gateway and database is MSsql one

Comment: Was the problem resolved ?

Comment: I have found another workaround if the current solution doesn't work for you. You could try azure hybrid connection which can lead you to connect your on-premises database connection please refer this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I need to truncate table before insert records. Is this possible with Azure logic apps?***

Yeah you can do it on Logic App with out writing any SP.

There is builtin connector under SQL that is  `Execute a SQL Query` on logic app designer. You have to use that connector.

***If so how can i achieve this?***

You can write `RAW` sql command there. See the below example.

I have a table like below:

```sql
  CREATE TABLE AzureSqlTable(
        [Id] [int] PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [FirstName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [LastName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [Email] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    )
    GO
```

**Your Case:**

> In your case I had tried to `INSERT` data using `SQL` Executor command
>   before INSERT operation I just TRUNCATE that table Like below:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE AzureSqlTable

INSERT INTO AzureSqlTable VALUES('PassFirstNameParam','PassLastNameParam','PassEmailParam')
```

I have defined a HTTP Request JSON schema with my parameter value and pass it to the `SQL Executor Connector`. See the screen shot below:

[image]

**On Premises Operation:**

For on premises query execution you have to configure like below:

[image]

**Note:** For On Prem connection configuration you could refer this [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-connection#connect-to-on-premises-data)

This is how you could can TRUNCATE your table before INSERT operation. As you already know how to  configure SQL connection. So I haven't put that in.

Comment: Are you sure `Execute a SQL query` is available for On-premises installations?

Comment: Yeah its available you could refer this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-connection#connect-to-on-premises-data)

Comment: @AdAstra I have updated the answer with on premises configuration. Thanks

Comment: Do you have an instance where you have tried this? Because the two SQL servers I have available both yield the result `Error executing the api '/$metadata.json/datasets/default/query/sql'` when I select this action. I wonder what prerequisites there are for this action.

Comment: Yeah, I have connected `Azure SQL` instance to with my on premises SQL instance and and then executed that query on Azure portal db instances that work as expected. Did you able to established  your SQL connection on logic apps?

Comment: In my case, I am reading from an on-premises instance which is where I wanted to execute the query. However, that action from logic apps is the error in my comment above. So in my case, there is no Azure SQLs. The connection to the on-premises instance was established on the Azure portal and the action `Get-Rows` work fine with a query parameter. It just bugs me that the run query does not work on the instance. Hence why I was so surprised that it worked for you. (SQL server 2014)

Comment: I am using SQL 2016 Enterprise. But I am pretty much sure about azure portal. Since I am working Azure portal SQL I usually connect that to my on premises instance. Main things is functionality is  related to Azure Logic App, so connection establish is important. I don't know about if there is any version limitation. Would you kindly try with Azure SQL by connecting your on premises SQL?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195703/discussion-between-adastra-and-md-farid-uddin-kiron).

Comment: Sure we can to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Write a stored procedure on the SQL server that truncates the table, call upon that in logic apps via the SQL connector through the data gateway. After that, you could inject the data.

Comment: Is there a way to do it through logic app without writing sp?

Comment: @Thill Yeah you can do it without SP. See the steps below.